# Is using an offensive flag for age bigotry the correct thing to do?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736243/ai-asking-age-and-says-its-thought-about-your-age) as offensive, as it contained a "funny program" that declared people over the age of 50 as "dead". If we substituted race or gender for age, that would clearly be hate literature.

A moderator disputed the flag:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Let's see what the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) has to say on the subject:

3. **Don't be a jerk.** These are just a few examples. If you see them, *flag them*:

   ...

   - **Bigotry of any kind.** Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are just a few examples; when in doubt, just don't.)

I followed that guidance because I believe moderator intervention is required - the post needs to be deleted, not just closed.

I was born in 1965 - you do the math. Since the community guidelines of inclusion apparently don't apply to age, I guess us old fogies are unwelcome.

Comment: This kind of comments do not need _moderator intervention_. Just flagging as rude or offensive should be sufficient.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Read my post, please. I flagged it as offensive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My flag for "offensive" also got disputed.

Comment: Apparently age bigotry bigotry is NOT OK on Meta.

Comment: The question also offends people under the age of 7.

Comment: That's no problem @Stryner. They aren't allowed to have accounts on any of the sites. So feel free to insult those bed wetting noobs.

Comment: Well, judging from the voting, taunts like this are fine if it only affects 2.4% of the users.  Or if you've been around for 50 years to have seen them all perhaps.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question that specifies that the program is intended to be used by *people*.  For all we know, the program could be intended for horses or other animals that rarely live past the age of 50.

Comment: Can Mr. Ed type as well?  Oh, wait, only 2.4% of the users know who he is :)

Comment: @HansPassant I'm 27 and I get that. your stats may be off ;)

Comment: @Patrice, where on Earth have they shown Mr Ed in the last two decades? I'm of a similar age to Mogsdad and I haven't seen it since I was a kid. Just out of interest, are you across St Trinians, Ma and Pa Kettle, Laurel and Hardy, and possibly others? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I get the reference, I didn't say I ever watched it :p. My dad used to talk about that horse a lot is all

Comment: Seriously? That's not even close to being offensive.  Unless you went to the Yale school of how to find offense in small things.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would have been to edit the "offending" wording out of the question.

BTW I handled the flags by *disputing* them (yes there were several) and stand by my decision (disclaimer: I am over 50). Yes, they had merit but there were better ways of handling this - if nothing else at least three > 20k users had to have seen the question and they could have cast delete votes.

The only difference with racist/sexist language is that I would have edited out myself (if that were possible) rather than waiting for the community to do so.

Comment: Look at this old fogey putting another old fogey in his place. (Yeah, yeah, I'm one to talk, I'm not even half the OP's age, I know.)

Comment: If this was the only flag I'd ever raised, you might be right in assuming I was doing so for my own gratification. However, that isn't the case. The community guideline is that **bigotry is not tolerated. At all.**

Comment: @Mogsdad And the moderator ruling was that this wasn't bigotry.

Comment: @Mogsdad my dictionary tells me that bigotry requires "unreasonable prejudice or intolerance". The only unreasonable intolerance I see here is from you.

Comment: @Mogsdad I think you're missing the point. It's true that bigotry is not tolerated, but in this case it didn't need moderator intervention. With your rep, you can easily just edit the question yourself and remove the bigotry from it.

Comment: @Mogsdad The question is bad but honestly I don't believe the intention was to offend anyone, however to remove the discussion about it, I've deleted it.

Comment: @Oldskool So where is the line where a mod should get involved versus it being edited out?

Comment: @DavidG - If you can edit it without destroying the sense of the post do so. If it's just a rant or otherwise un-salvageable then flag.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm cool with that. So essentially if a post can be turned into a valid post with some basic edits, do that instead of flagging.

Comment: @DavidG especially in a circumstance where there is NO WAY to destroy the OP's post with such an edit (just remove "dead" and add "very old" to it, or change the "50" to "150"). I mean it's not like the root of what the OP is asking is about that turn of phrase over an age

Comment: @DavidG: Compare "How do I foo the bar? **EDIT** I hope you all die in a fire" and "I hope you all die in a fire." (as original revision)

Comment: *Are you really that sensitive about a line in a poorly written question that implies people over 50 are dead?* Yes I am.

Comment: I'm with Mogsdad here. As mentioned in the (Meta) question, would the same kind of question be deemed acceptable if it were talking about race or gender? I hope not. Yes, editing is certainly one approach - but I think the flag is entirely reasonable too. Ignoring bigotry doesn't make it go away, IME.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The problem is that these flags have inherent destructive consequences for both the *post* and the user. I can see wanting to mete out a reputation demerit against a user for bad behaviour (in which case you really should be getting a moderator involved instead - though preferably via a custom flag), but if a post is otherwise harmless without the offensive content then should the entire thing be removed? Especially if it's a question with useful and clean answers? This is not about ignoring bigotry, but about handling it appropriately.

Comment: @Boltclock: Would that line of reasoning apply to a racist, homophobic or sexist post too? Basically that sounds like a flaw in the handling of offensive posts rather than an indication that this post should be tolerated.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Consider a programming question about strings, that happens to use a racist slur as an input string. It's a useful question, or it would be if it wasn't for the racist slur. Should the question be deleted, or the racist slur replaced by something harmless such as "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"? Remember that bad behaviour can be dealt with separately from content.

Comment: @JonSkeet - If the post can be salvaged by editing then you should do just that. If it the post is nothing more than a diatribe then by all means flag. By all means flag the post with "other" so we can check out the rest of the user's contributions.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've had offensive flags declined in the past by moderators who said editing out the offensive parts was adequate, so it seems to be a party line.

Comment: @Boltclock Sure, it's worth fixing the post. It's *not* good to just laugh off (tolerate) the problem though. Look at the quoted text in the question - we claim that offensive material won't be tolerated... I think that line should be stuck to, rather than taking a "don't be so sensitive" line... The same line that catcallers have been using for years when women protest.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: That I can agree with, and I'll readily admit that my topmost comment wasn't helping matters any. Especially considering I myself was the subject of ageist prejudice on this very site a long time ago...

Comment: @JonSkeet - yeah. Perhaps a bad choice of words there. But everyone who saw the post **failed to edit it**, so why devolve that decision to a moderator?

Comment: @ChrisF Because we are used to flagging when something appears to be offensive. I have not seen guidance to edit before now. In future, I will use a little more judgement.

Comment: @ChrisF: I'd have been fine with a response of "Yes, that post is unacceptable - but as you have enough rep to edit it, that's the best approach in this case." And if that really *is* the system intention, perhaps it should be highlighted when one is flagging a post as offensive? ("Are you sure you need to flag this rather than just editing it yourself? Consider reducing the moderator load.")

Comment: Is there any particular reason the Help Center doesn't say that offensive posts should be edited if possible?

Comment: @BSMP - I don't know. Perhaps that's worth raising as a [meta-tag:feature-request].

Comment: @Killercam One has to wonder, then, why you took the time to comment.

Comment: Because it is ridiculous and it _seems_ that this needs highlighting...

Comment: @Killercam It doesn't really matter what was intended when the user posted but how others thought the post meant. The consequences of actions are often based on what they are thought to mean rather then what they actually did mean.

Comment: Well in that case, I find your comment above hugely offensive as it assumes that I did not have the foresight or intelligence to work this out for myself. As such, I will write another post on meta where we can discuss the human right to be offended and victimized by everything possible without exception. Actually, in true meta-style I have just offended myself and am going to flag this comment for moderation.

Comment: @JonSkeet The OP was calling for posts that include ageism to be deleted outright, describing an ageist joke as "hate literature" (which it isn't - whatever your view on ageist jokes, this one clearly isn't meant to incite *hatred* of the old) and accusing the *entire site* of being bigots who consider old people unwelcome, purely because a moderator didn't delete this post. It's entirely fair to condemn the OP as over-sensitive in that context; you can calmly call for a sterner response to ageist jokes without condemning the entire community as hateful bigots who want to exclude over-50s.

Comment: @MarkAmery: To start with, I agree with you that the post doesn't need to be deleted. But I don't see where the OP claimed that was "condemning the entire community as hateful bigots" - isn't it reasonable to point out that ageist bigotry isn't being dealt with as other bigotry would be? That seems reasonably calm to me, and doesn't seem to be calling anyone else a "hateful bigot". Or to put it another way - how could the OP have pointed out what they viewed as a difference in how ageism is handled vs other discrimination *without* incurring your claim that they're being oversensitive?

Comment: @JonSkeet okay, "hateful bigots" is overstatement, but in his final sentence *"Since the community guidelines of inclusion apparently don't apply to age, I guess us old fogies are unwelcome."*, the OP is clearly tarring the entire community based upon this post and how it was moderated. There's two elements to the overreaction here: one in calling the post in question "hateful" (it plainly isn't) and the other in condemning the entire community over a post barely anyone in it had seen. I doubt the reaction to the OP would've been as negative had it not been for those two factors.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I think you're being oversensitive to someone expressing their discontent ;) You reacted with an overstatement (in your own words) - was that a reasonable thing to do? It's an entirely *natural* thing to do - and I believe it's what the OP did as well. Rather than condemn *them* for it, wouldn't it have been more productive to react to the underlying problem, which isn't hard to discern? I think we can do that without claiming that anyone is being oversensitive.

Comment: @JonSkeet unlike the OP, I have a 600 character limit which restricts how carefully I can pick my words, but I take your point about hypocrisy nonetheless. Once you take out the over-the-top rhetoric about hatred and  unwelcomeness from the post, though, what underlying problem is left to address? Is this about ageist jokes being treated differently to racial or sexist jokes? Nobody has given any evidence that this is actually the case. Is it about editing being an inadequate response to bigoted jokes and such posts needing total deletion? If so, that's not how the question has been framed.

Comment: @JonSkeet (And for the record, since *your* take on this is that its about inconsistency in how different kinds of bigotry are handled, if a woman or racial minority had posted on Meta in response to some similarly mildly sexist or racist code, and had similarly grandly claimed that women or $racial_minority were unwelcome on Stack Overflow on the basis of one post and demanded total deletion of the content while simultaneously declining to use their editing powers and thereby leaving the content that offended them on the site, I'd react with similar irritation and dismissal.)

Comment: @MarkAmery: I think asking a clarifying comment about the purpose of the post would have been a very reasonable response. I *suspect* the OP feels that for other offensive posts, they would have simply been deleted - and if that's not the case, then that could have been clarified fairly simply. I guess my basic messages are: a) claiming that people are oversensitive when they react to posts of this kind isn't helpful; see my catcalling analogy earlier; b) the more people that keep calm heads and avoid hyperbole, the better. And yes, I'm certainly guilty of hyperbole from time to time too.

Comment: *Perhaps that's worth raising as a feature-request.* - Would that need to be changed via Meta SE or does each site technically have their own version of that page?

Comment: @BSMP as far as I know it's the same network wide, but you can make the request here if you like

Comment: I propose to add a new-stackable badge, the badge of **biggotry** or **douchebaggery**

Comment: So, someone uses offensive language, and we edit it out. How does that discourage them from doing it again in their next question/answer? And the one after that? "Oh, those mewling PC types always edit my posts, I just ignore it." Offensive behavior should have *consequences*, not just get whitewashed away with an edit. Seems to me the right answer is edit *and* flag, and the mod should accept the flag and deal with the underlying problem: The user's inappropraite behavior on the site. If we think a -100 for a first offense is too heavy, it can be lower for the first offense or two.

Comment: @T.J. you often find that the offensive language is the result of frustration. If it's not then it's highly likely that the post isn't a question or answer anyway and in that case a flag *is* appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisF 'tis true, my experience is that truly *offensive* questions or answers are indeed very rare (whereas with comments, sadly, it's a whole 'nother story). That said, whether the bad behavior is the result of frustration or not doesn't really matter, does it? It should still have consequences (again, possibly graduated ones). If there are really that few, we're not adding moderator burden by flagging. (I should say that I wouldn't have flagged the question in question; I'd've edited it and commented. [And I'm only a year younger than the OP.] I'm speaking of the general case here.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If someone's throwing around words that are uncontroversially slurs, then flagging and letting someone with a bigger stick address their behaviour is reasonable. If - as I expect is typical - it's in contention whether anyone but a tiny over-sensitive minority would ever find the content offensive, then surely it's better to do nothing or, if you truly must, edit to remove the offending content while preserving its meaning? I see no sense in flagging in cases - like the code in question here, or your use of the word "whitewashing" - where barely anyone is going to take offence.

Comment: @MarkAmery: ***sigh*** You know that "whitewashing" is not in any way related to race, that's a strawman. I see you're back to your "oversensitive" thing again. I agree with Jon: Not helpful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, I know that "whitewashing", as you're using it, isn't a reference to race; I don't see how that makes it a strawman, unless you believe that the OP of the post in dispute here intended their post to cause offence or expected that it would do so. I'm not sure what your issue with me describing Mogsdad as "oversensitive" is given that you've said that you've said yourself that you wouldn't have flagged this post. Aren't you agreeing with me, *at least* on the particular post this thread is about, just in different words?

Comment: @MarkAmery: No, I am not agreeing with you.