# Edit a post that can (possibly) contain offensive/unnecesary text

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, offensive

I have the following doubt

Recently I saw a Q/A on the site [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344045/installing-node-js-and-npm-on-windows-10/27344046?noredirect=1#comment55349504_27344046)

In the answer the user posted the following:

> "*http://nodejs.org/download/ download the 64 bits version, **32 is
>   for hipsters***

I'm not a hipster at all, but I believe that certain group of people might find that depreciatory, or even offensive, the user itself rejected the edition and added this comment:

> "*Thanks for your edit, but please only edit when it improves the
>   answer. Refer to [stackoverflow.com/help/editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more on this
>   subject*"

To be honest, he seems right since none of the rules states that you should edit when then answer seems to have an offensive content.

I don't think that flagging the answer is the correct way since actually, it is a helpful answer, so, what would be the right step in here?

Comment: You _should_ edit out offensive content when you can salvage a post that way... But I'm not sure anyone would see that as more than a "before it was cool" joke... It's not anything _more_ than a joke, really. Can you clarify why you thought it might be offensive, so we can understand your side a bit better?

Comment: I can't fathom how that could constitute offensive content.

Comment: Who is going to be offended by that?

Comment: Also note: Downvotes on Meta tend to indicate disagreement. A lot of people likely disagree that this is in anyway offensive. (And a _lot_ of questions about offensive content have popped up the past few days, so some of them might be because people are tired of seeing it... Can't say for sure though.)

Comment: @Kendra perhaps it's just a cultural difference, where I live using the term "hipster" in such context is considered an offense.

Comment: @BilltheLizard what if it says "retards" instead of "hipsters" would it still be non-offensive?

Comment: People who are retarded can't help that they're retarded. Yes, that's offensive.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that area (since your general location is in your profile) found "hipsters" in that context to be offensive. I might have to look that up sometime and look into it a bit for background as to why. Around here, "hipsters" is just another general group people identify with, like "nerd" or "car enthusiast" or the like.

Comment: What is and isn't offensive is determined by community consensus anyways. So if an appreciable number of people find it, it is. If you want to clean it up, go ahead, but know that your edits are subject to community review and you may have to defend them.

Comment: @Magisch I understand that, but the edit wasn't rejected by the community itself or another member, but the OP of the answer, that's why I came here to ask, to know, i read all of your opinions.

Comment: @DannyG well if something is genuenly offensive and OP keeps rolling back edits edit it out one last time and then flag for mod attention. They can and will lock posts to stop edit wars, and in case of offensive content, they will pin the non-offensive version.

Comment: @Kendra well, nerd in here is used also as a derogatory adjective. unlike car enthusiast, and for the poor familiarity I have with the american culture (for an example) it appears to be the same.

Comment: I don't perceive that as offensive, but it is __unnecessary noise__.  Removing it on that basis is ok.  As always, fix all aspects of the post when editing.

Comment: @DannyG Remind me not to visit your area anytime soon- I love identifying as a nerd... (And I'd hate to accidentally offend someone in doing so! :()

Comment: @Kendra I doubt anyone wanna come here, anytime soon, (just read the news) :D

Comment: For what it's worth, I did create a feature request to update the Help Center to state that [editing out offensive content is what you're supposed to do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310551/correction-for-the-be-nice-page-in-the-help-center).

Comment: @ryanyuyu yes, but I never believed that it would be brought back because someone posted a question with "hipsters" in it

Comment: @Patrice I'm a programmer, not some proud of myself software engineer, and I fight that term insulting as such. (Disclaimer: I actually have no issue with software engineers. Sorry, Engineers! :)) (Serious response: It comes to a case of culture in this one, though. It's not just a it _may_ be offensive, but is apparently _actually_ offensive to call a person a hipster in Danny's culture. So he's not trying to prevent someone from _potentially_ being offended in this case. I find that to be a bit different from Cerbrus' post.)

Comment: @Kendra not really, that's basically the intent of Cerbrus' thread in my mind : to prove that if we start allowing every possible interpretation of every possible word, someone will be offended one way or another. This is proof of that. If I need to word my questions in mind with "oh my god, somewhere, THIS PERSON may find this offensive", we'll never stop

Comment: You can't compare one thing to the other, I just believe that tagging something you consider bad practice, with a "cultural" group isn't the right way to act. simple as that.

Comment: @Patrice Also, if you check Danny's comment on Ed's answer, it appears that Danny fits into the category there, so... If he was actually offended to be _called_ a hipster because it's offensive in his culture, then that makes sense too.

Comment: @Patrice And you don't have to actively consider that- Just be kind enough to accept that cultures are different and be polite about it if you accidentally use a phrase that's offensive to another culture. As pointed out in Tim's answer to the same question. You don't _have_ to actively prevent it, but if someone lets you know, at least act in kind and listen about it.

Comment: @Kendra he fits in the category? doesn't his question state "I'm not a hipster at all, but I believe that certain group of people might find that depreciatory, or even offensive, the user itself rejected the edition and added this comment" So we go back to Cerbrus' thread of "well yeah if we start removing every possible offensive term to someone, we'll never get anywhere"

Comment: @Kendra I never stated I got offended, see Ed Cotrell answer below, I just  don't fit in that description, but I don't find cultural ways for a person of being, offensive

Comment: @DannyG I didn't say you did, because you didn't say you did. I said that _if_ you did it would also make sense. As in if you _had_ been offended, it also makes sense you'd want to fix it.

Comment: @Kendra Ok now I am really confused! (The comment was supposed to be tagged to patrice actually, my apologizes for it)

Comment: Ooooooo... sneaky comment deletions!

Comment: @Will which is a shame, yours was funny (even if I can understand it being flagged). I'm surprised mine got flagged enough to be removed (I mean... FFS is THAT insulting now?)

Comment: @Patrice It's bullying against PHP programmers different cat.

Comment: @Will I was just going to comment on the irony of someone being offended by the word 'hipster' but then equating some downvotes on their answer to something many would find truly offensive and the comment had gone.

Comment: @DannyG to my latest comment? Basically there was a thread on meta recently (ryanyuyu linked it higher) where a user was asking where will the trend of thinking anything can be offensive and removed stop. In this case, you wanted to edit something because someone somewhere might find it offensive. The thread Cerbrus started was trying to see where should we stop this overzealous policing of ourselves

Comment: @Patrice I read all that thread and I agree, but seriously I think some things have no comparison, when a term starts being seen as derogatory it is because some people use it to offend someone else, and i believe that even if OP was using it as a joke, the intention was offensive, otherwise unnecesary.

Comment: Same as with Nerd, do I find that offensive when I get called by it? no, for me it's a compliment, but the people that use it they do it because they think they'll offend you with it.

Comment: @DannyG I dunno for you, but I shrug off these things. I do not give a flying f.... about what people who are basically strangers think about me. If someone is insensitive enough to use words to try and offend someone, he's not worth my time. And if the OP was using it as a joke, why does it have to be offensive? hipsters ARE characterized by their love of older trends, no? So... is it really an offense to associate them with 32 bits when 64 bits is getting more and more prominent? I don't think so

Comment: using 32 bits is not the same as for instance using a typewritter while having computers, it's more related to the hardware you have to use it, but well that will be an entire different thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if `hipster` is offensive or not - but it is *certainly* unnecessary verbage that has no relation to the answer.  It should be edited out, and if the edit is rolled back, flag with a custom flag (as with any other edit disagreement).  Flags don't mean the moderator has to blow up the answer: they can take the appropriate action (editing it out) and then notify the user why they took it, or lock the post if needed.

SO aims at professionalism, and I certainly wouldn't put that in my documentation here at work.

Comment: I completely agree with you.

Comment: I'd maybe agree with this if it was part of a post cleanup. An edit that consisted only of removing the 'offending' remark is certainly too trivial and should be rejected in the edit queue. Simply put, removing it doesn't make the answer better, and isn't worthy of an edit. And I can honestly say I've put far 'worse flavor' into documentation at work.

Answer (score 24):

The right approach is to let this one go. Hipsters are characterized by:

> The hipster subculture is one of affluent or middle class young Bohemians who reside in gentrifying neighborhoods, broadly associated with indie and alternative music, **a varied non-mainstream fashion sensibility** (including vintage and thrift store-bought clothes), generally progressive political views, organic and artisanal foods, and **alternative lifestyles**.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipster_(contemporary_subculture)). Yes, I just linked Wikipedia...

In my experience, the term usually also applies to ironic or deliberately anachronistic choices with respect to lots of things, including technology. A 32-bit system is pretty anachronistic at this point, so the term seems to fit.

Also, the mere fact that someone *might*, hypothetically, find something offensive does not make it actually offensive. The edit in this case did not solve a real problem, in that no one had (yet) been offended. Nor was offense inevitable. Some terms are *always* offensive; this one is not.

Now, if hipsters appear and flood the comments with disagreement, I may reconsider. The question is whether Meta loads properly on a 32-bit system these days...

Comment: tbh, i have a backup PC running with 32-bits, mostly because the low RAM  capacity it has, can't run with 64-bits, based on that theory that turns me into a "hipster"?

Comment: You will be surprised to learn that while at work I browse SO mainly from a Windows XP 32 bit machine :D

Comment: @DannyG It's not like being a hipster is a bad thing, at least not in the area I'm from. Like I said above, it's just another group people identify with. If you don't identify with it, then that's cool. I personally wouldn't be offended because someone called _me_ a hipster, for instance due to liking Pokemon "before (and technically for my age group, after) it was cool." Now if it's offensive in _your_ culture, maybe the OP will react in accordance with that if you (politely of course) explain it is, and why it is.

Comment: @DannyG :) I'm kidding, much like the author of the answer at issue (I think). I have at least a few 32-bit devices floating around, myself.

Comment: @Magisch Impressive! They need to upgrade you. :)

Comment: As a note, I let the author of the answer in question know about this post, @DannyG. If he checks it out, maybe he'll come to understand why you found it offensive and have a better understanding of why you edited his answer. (Whether he edits it back out is of course up to him, but at least he'll better understand where your edit was coming from.)

Comment: @EdCottrell Its actually partly by choice. I have a normal win7 machine (even a very decent one) but im forced to use a XP Machine to develop for some of the old legacy programs which won't run on Win7. (Like an Arcane extremely big VB6 Legacy app that is full of specific references and case handlings specifically for windows 98, 2000 and XP)

Comment: @Magisch Okay, that's fair.

Comment: Ed seems to know a lot about hipsters... hmm... :)

Comment: @Kendra Thanks, is not a big interest, I just try to do my part with the community and tried to understand the perception of the word from other people, my bad for not searching the word "hispter" before posting hehe

Comment: @EdCottrell Good luck on the election by the way

Comment: It's not really offensive, its just unnecessary text. An edit can take place(based on my experience in this site)

Comment: @PoolPartyRenekton No question: it's unnecessary. But if it's not offensive or spam, then the author is free to reject suggested edits.

Answer (score 14):

As the user of a 32-bit OS - I can safely say that I don't find that offensive.

But then again, I'm too busy eating artisanal foods and buying thrift-store clothes to care.

*(Also, Meta loads fine on x32 ;-) )*

Comment: Upvoted for the laughs.

Comment: Downvote because your avatar is way too mainstream for you to actually be a hipster.  (Also, you haven't actually address the core aspect of how to proceed.)

Comment: And Macro Man wins.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Don't you see? I'm using a mainstream image for my avatar _before_ the other hipsters do it - _before_ it's cool. \*nonchalant sigh\*

Comment: @MacroMan ohhhhhh.  That's really [insert obscure slang term meaning clever].

Comment: Just because you use a 32-bit OS does not mean you are a hipster. But if you are a hipster, you are more likely to use a 32-bit OS. It's an overlapping Venn diagram (rendering on vellum using an 18th century printing press, of course :)).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I dunno, my Mum was one of the original hipsters (she's now in her 70s as most original hipster are- in our time) and she uses a 64 bit os..  mind you she uses it to play farmville.. hehe \blinking hippes hahahaha

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of the content in question!

The hipster remark is not meant to be offensive; I am quite sure we can all agree on that. However, even when something is not meant to be offensive, it might still offend.

I believe a small remark like that adds a bit of personality to the answers at no expense of quality. To me, hipster is just a fashion trend and in no way personal. In that sense, it did work as I got a positive comment on it, which also got upvoted by other users. This leads me to believe that it put a smile on some faces, which is always nice! :-)

Answer (score -1):

This actually raises another question of whether it's appropriate to be funny or witty in here. Some people without sense of humor or coming from a different cultural background or not sharing some view would always find some comment supposedly intended to be witty offensive. So we can either follow the "majority of our visitors don't find this offensive" rule or just ban jokes outright to avoid the conflicts entirely.

Answer (score -4):

I can't see how that could possibly be genuinely offensive to anyone. That being said, if you find that it is, go ahead and edit it out. Make sure you don't deface the post or remove necessary information and you're golden.

You can try to edit it out, and if the community thinks doing so is a good idea, it will get accepted.